# How to freeze applications on rooted android device

Tags: android, root, android-package-managers

How can I **Freeze/Unfreeze** applications on the rooted device like **Titanium Backup** app so that i make my app non-accessable from a rooted device. Any method to trace whether the device is rooted or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***i am using RootTools library to do disable/enable command***

```
CommandCapture command_enable = new CommandCapture(0,"pm enable "+ Package_Name);                           
RootTools.getShell(true).add(command_enable).waitForFinish();

CommandCapture command_disable = new CommandCapture(0,"pm disable "+ Package_Name);
RootTools.getShell(true).add(command_disable).waitForFinish();
```

Comment: Do you know if there is also a way to check if it is "frozen"?

Comment: Why use `CommandCapture`, when it is an extension of `Command` meant to hold the output? http://code.google.com/p/roottools/source/browse/trunk/Developmental/RootTools_sdk3_generic/src/com/stericson/RootTools/Command.java?r=208

Answer (score 1):

You could actually try to run a root command and catch the response and determine if the device is rooted.

Taking code from [here](http://muzikant-android.blogspot.mx/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html) and modifying it a little to suit your needs, I think it could go like this:

```
public static boolean canRunRootCommands()
       {
          boolean retval = false;
          Process suProcess;

          try
          {
             suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

             DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
             DataInputStream osRes = new DataInputStream(suProcess.getInputStream());

             if (null != os && null != osRes)
             {
                retval = true;

                /*
                 *if got to this point, its safe to assume the 
                 *device is rooted and here you can do something 
                 *to tell your app that su is present. Or you could 
                 *use the bool return of this function to know that the 
                 *device is rooted and make the app act different.
                 */

             }
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
             // Can't get root !
             // [...] meaning that the device is not rooted

             retval = false;
          }

          return retval;
       }
```

I have not tested this but I'm sure it will help you. Or at least it will point you in the right way.